Currency set in session file, but browser shows other currency
I have a shop with 2 currencies (A and B). Currency is correctly set in Magento session file in var/session as currency A.
For some reason some frontend pages are sometimes shown with the wrong currency B. I checked the session currency right after seeing wrong currency B in frontend and the session file had currency A set.
Could Varnish be responsible of this behaviour somehow, because if I flush caches and reload the page it shows the correct currency A? Is there anything else that could cause this?

Bypassing Varnish did no solve the problem and it also happens with default Magento cache. So I guess the problem is deeper.
